# Create django File object from online url

Tags: python, django

So I want to save some images to my django models through the shell, with the added twist that the said images would come from an online resource, a url.

As per the requests [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) I can get the file to disk thus:

```
import requests

img = requests.get("image_url", stream=True)
with open("name.jpg", "wb") as fd:
    for chunk in img.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

I could write the file to disk, then convert to a django file object like so

```
from django.core.files import File
img = File(open(choice(IMAGES), "rb"))
```

But I need a way to bypass the read and write to/from disk while still ending up with the django File object. I've tried `io.BytesIO` and `io.StringIO` but each time I end up with an `exception`.

Comment: Include the code that caused the exception and the full traceback. It is possible to save a django file using io.BytesIO, but we can't suggest any solution without knowing what exactly is wrong. [mcve]

Comment: OK. I'll do that once I get home. But I'll first try using 'io.BytesIO'